# Automatically increment number across the whole document with biblatex using the authoryear style

Tags: biblatex, citing, authoryear

I am currently using biblatex with the authoryear citation style.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
\footcite[p.~2]{Test.1}
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
\footcite[p.~2]{Test.1}
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

\chapter{Ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   
\footcite[p.~2]{Test.1}
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   
\footcite[p.~2]{Test.2}
Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

\end{document}
```

It basically looks exactly like I want in the document, but it keeps resetting the index/counter for the footnotes on every page, so the first citation on every page starts with the number 1, then 2, and so on:
[image: example]

However, I want it to keep incrementing the index for every new citation across the whole document, so in my example it should use 1 for the first citation, 2 for the second one, 3 for the third one and so on. How can I do that?

Warning: I am a complete noob in Latex and this is my first ever attempt to use it. If my question lacks any information which is required to answer it, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide a code example that shows your undesired result. I.e. in this case it should span several pages. It will be easier for us to answer your question. You may also want to add a sketch, of how it should look like in the end.

Comment: @MS-SPO I just edited my question. Is it better like this?

Comment: this is not done by biblatex. Something else in your preamble activates footnote numbers per page -- perhaps your unknown class.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but what does that mean? How can I figure out what's causing this and fix the issue? I am not even sure if this is done per page because in my actual document in some cases it seems to continue incrementing the index sometimes, but sometimes not. I don't even understand what causes it to start from 1 again in some cases.

Comment: well the footnote counter can be reset by page or by chapter or by other things. But you will have to provide a small but complete example (starting with \documentclass). Without it we can't know what reset your document uses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Weird, I already had the documentclass in my question the entire time. No idea why it wasn't displaying it. Can you see it now?

Comment: well the class will reset the footnote counter with every chapter. If you don't want that use `\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for!